# Python Requests - Why doesn't POST fall back to GET in case of no POST data?

Tags: python, python-requests

Running `python` version 3.5.1 and `requests` module version 2.9.1

Old version that worked - `python` version 2.7.9, unfortunately do not have the `requests` module version.

---

In previously scenarios there have been cases where I would only need to work with `POST` or `GET` requests.

Previously, with the `requests` module, when specifying a `POST` request and set the `data` keyword argument to `None`, the request would default back to a `GET` request.

```
request = requests.post(url=self.url, headers=self.headers,
                        data=self.data, timeout=self.timeout, 
                        proxies=self.proxies, verify=False)
```

This was very nifty as you could write a generic `request` function that covers both `GET` and `POST` requests in one block. However this does not seem to be the case anymore which causes me to write some ugly code like so:

```
if self.data:
    request = requests.post(url=self.url, headers=self.headers,
                            data=self.data, timeout=self.timeout, 
                            proxies=self.proxies, verify=False)
else:
    request = requests.get(url=self.url, headers=self.headers,
                           data=None, timeout=self.timeout, 
                           proxies=self.proxies, verify=False)
```

Which is not really desirable. I have gone through the `requests` Github and documentation to see if there is anything that documents this however that does not seem to be the case.

Has this functionality been removed, or has it changed in newer versions?

Comment: Wow, that alleged old behaviour is *disgusting*. You can have POST requests with empty bodies. Magically using a different request type, when the user has explicitly requested `.post`, seems insane.

Comment: @JeremyBanks - You could specify empty bodies, only when it was set to `None` would it fall back to a `GET` request. The `.post` was indeed somewhat counter-intuitive but I preferred adding a well explained single comment than having to copy the same block in two different places (becomes a maintenance issue). May be a personal preference :-)

Comment: Turns out, there are even better alternatives to what I was previously doing!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could also just use the `request()` function instead of the `get` and `post` convenience functions.

```
import requests

response = requests.request('POST' if self.data else 'GET', url=self.url, 
                             headers=self.headers, data=self.data or None, 
                             timeout=self.timeout, proxies=self.proxies, verify=False)
```

Comment: I feel this is the better alternative as it's kept within the `requests` module. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You can make the code prettier:

```
if self.data:
    fn = requests.post
else:
    fn = requests.get

request = fn(url=self.url, headers=self.headers, data=self.data or None,
             timeout=self.timeout, proxies=self.proxies, verify=False)
```

(I realize this isn't an answer, but I don't know how to post formatted code in a comment.)

Comment: I like this! Thanks John :-). Unfortunately as you mentioned, this does not directly answer the question so it wouldn't be all too fair to mark it as the answer.

Comment: this __is__ an answer. Even if an nswer to the problem, not to the question - but that is doubly useful, once the question itself is asking for undesirable behavior of the underlying library.